# How to use Webhooks with Exporter.send method?

Tags: javascript, webhooks, dronedeploy

I've been trying to use a webhook to export a file to a URL with the Exporter.send method. The exports have been successful, as they've been coming to my email. However, I'm using a webhook service online and it is not registering any pings to the URL even though the exports are being sent to my email.

Here's the code I used, basically pulled straight from the documentation.

```
 dronedeployApi.Exporter.send({
                layer: 'NDVI Toolbox',
                email: emails,

                file_format: 'geotiff',
                merge: mergeCheckbox.checked ? true : false,
                projection: projectionValue.value,
                resolution: resolutionValue.value === 0 ? 'native' : resolutionValue.value,
                webhook: {
                    url: 'http://webhook.site/3d10872c-a56e-4b2b-aa3b-b8c0334e8f5f' 
                }
            })
            .then(function(exportId) {
                    dronedeployApi.Messaging.showToast('NDVI export successful!', {
                        timeout: -1         
                    });
                },
                function(error) {
                    dronedeployApi.Messaging.showToast(error, {
                        timeout: -1
                    });
                }
            );
```

Thoughts on what might be going wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

( I am an Engineer and DroneDeploy )
The code looks fine, I am going to create a barebones app here that does exports in the next few hours. Expect a response from me soon.

-- Edit. I have confirmed that I receive export webhooks. Without knowing the actual url you used or the situation with your webserver, I cannot confirm what your specific problem may be.

However, Dronedeploy was experiencing issues throughout the day, leading to intermittent instability. I would recommend trying again.

If you continue to have trouble, we can do a more private conversation, regarding your implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the response - I tried again but unfortunately it's not working. How can I reach out privately?

Comment: Also, as a follow up - I used this webhooks tester to track requests to the URL in my code: [https://webhook.site/#/](https://webhook.site/#/). I tried RequestBin as well and it didn't work either.

Comment: ah i didnt realize that webhook.site was an actual site, and not you just removing a private url that you dont want public at the moment.
I will test with webhook.site , your exact code, and see what i can come up with.

Comment: @singhcpt : actually I just tested a basic post against webhook.site, and it gave me back an error

`request = require('request');
console.log(process.argv[2])
request.post(process.argv[2], { json: { body: true}} , function (err, req, res) {
 console.log(err, res);
});
`
the response gave back error json with some report about a mysql problem

Comment: http://webhook.site/e847edd9-8437-45ee-957d-dcca9795cdc7
null { success: false,
  error:
   { code: '23000',
     message: 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 19 NOT NULL constraint failed: requests.user_agent (SQL: insert into "requests" ("token_id", "ip", "hostname", "method", "user_agent", "content", "headers", "url", "uuid", "updated_at", "created_at") values (e847edd9-8437-45ee-
..truncated... 
http://webhook.site/e847edd9-8437-45ee-957d-dcca9795cdc7, 058cee43-1f12-4919-9a0a-286d1f766624, 2017-07-25 16:33:05, 2017-07-25 16:33:05))' } }

Comment: Have you tried with Request Bin? (Just as a heads up, I used the uniquely  generated URLs they give you, not the url https://webhook.site). I'm guessing this means this is not an issue with my code, but rather the tester I'm using. However, I find it odd that it wouldn't work for two different webhook testers online. What URL did you originally use to test your app when it worked? Thanks!